# array with tags and sub_tags

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm not sure if this question has been answered elsewhere, as I'm unsure how to express myself clearly.
I have an array that contains: tag, tag_id and inside this array another array with sub_tags. I want to count the number of occurrences of tags in my articles. 
Here is my array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [tag_id] => 1
        [tag] => vestas
        [sub_tag] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tag_id] => 2
        [tag] => novo nordisk
        [sub_tag] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [tag_id] => 3
        [tag] => stock
        [sub_tag] => Array
            (
                [0] => stocks
                [1] => stock market
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [tag_id] => 4
        [tag] => bil
        [sub_tag] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [tag_id] => 5
        [tag] => flower
        [sub_tag] => Array
            (
                [0] => flowers
            )

    )

)
```

I want to count occurrence of these tags in my articles. And the sub_tags should give points to the main tag. For example if I have an article that sounds like this:

"Vestas is a great company, the stocks are doing well on the stock exchange"

This article would give 1 count to "vestas" tag and 2 counts to "stock" as there are both stocks and  stock.

I prefer regex as I want to search the articles for exact words, and I'm thinking something like this:

```
   if (preg_match_all("/\b$sub_tags\b/", $content, $matches)) {
                    $sub_tag_count += count($matches[0]);
   }
```

And somehow use a foreach loop to loop through the sub_tags and main tag.

I appreciate your help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [array_walk_recursively](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) perhaps may be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to generate a regular expression consisting of the tag + subtags, then count the matches against that.

So:

```
Array
(
    [tag_id] => 3
    [tag] => stock
    [sub_tag] => Array
        (
            [0] => stocks
            [1] => stock market
        )

)
```

would generate the regex:

```
/(?:\bstock\b)|(?:\bstocks\b)|(?:\bstock market\b)/i
```

---

#### Example:

```
$tags = array (
    array (
        'tag_id' => 1,
        'tag' => 'vestas',
        'sub_tag' => array (),
    ),
    array (
        'tag_id' => 2,
        'tag' => 'novo nordisk',
        'sub_tag' => array (),
    ),
    array (
        'tag_id' => 3,
        'tag' => 'stock',
        'sub_tag' =>
            array (
                0 => 'stocks',
                1 => 'stock market',
            ),
    ),
    array (
        'tag_id' => 4,
        'tag' => 'bil',
        'sub_tag' => array (),
    ),
    array (
        'tag_id' => 5,
        'tag' => 'flower',
        'sub_tag' =>
            array (
                0 => 'flowers',
            ),
    ),
);

$text = "Vestas is a great company, the stocks are doing well on the stock exchange";

$count = [];
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $regex = '/(?:\b' . preg_quote($tag['tag'], '/');
    foreach ($tag['sub_tag'] as $sub) {
        $regex .= '\b)|(?:\b' . preg_quote($sub, '/');
    }
    $regex .= '\b)/i';
    $count[$tag['tag']] = preg_match_all($regex, $text);
}

print_r($count);
```

---

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [vestas] => 1
    [novo nordisk] => 0
    [stock] => 2
    [bil] => 0
    [flower] => 0
)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Simple and efficient solution!